# How cancel task with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: retrofit, reactive-programming, rx-java, okhttp

I have rest api.

```
@Get("/serveraction")
public Observable<String> myRequest(@Query("Data") String data);
```

I know, that okhttp has canceling functionality(by request object, by tag), but don't know how use it with retrofit and rxjava. What is the best way to realize canceling mechanism for network tasks with retrofit and rxjava?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the standard RxJava2 cancelling mechanism [Disposable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html).

```
Observable<String> o = retrofit.getObservable(..);
Disposable d = o.subscribe(...);

// later when not needed
d.dispose();
```

Retrofit RxJava call adapter will redirect this to okHttp's cancel.

RxJava1: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/46dc939a0dfb470b3f52edc88552f6f7ebb49f42/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/CallArbiter.java#L50-L53

RxJava2: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/46dc939a0dfb470b3f52edc88552f6f7ebb49f42/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/CallEnqueueObservable.java#L92-L95

Comment: FYI: I'm pretty sure [ObservableCallAdapterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit/ObservableCallAdapterFactory.java) in retrofit-adpaters is going to be part of as of yet unreleased Retrofit 2.0 and isn't currently part of Retrofit 1.9.  Unsubscribing as described above by @Sergii will still achieve the effect of your subscriber not getting the response, but how it is cancelled internally is less clean and you may see some thread interrupted exceptions (but they won't crash your app).

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 5):

The chosen answer is for Rx Java 1 and is not valid for RxJava2. For the latter, you can use Disposable. Follow this:

1. Define `CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable=new CompositeDisposable()` as a field in your `Activity` or `Fragment` in class.
2. Define the api using Retrofit 2 as something like this:

   ```
   public Observable<YourPojo> callApiWithRetrofit() {
       return getService(YourApiService.class).callApi();
   }
   ```
3. Define `Disposable`and add it to the `compositeDisposable` instance:

   ```
   Disposable disposable = callApiWithRetrofit().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(
           AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeWith(
           new DisposableObserver<List<YourPojo>>() {
               @Override
               protected void onStart() {
                   super.onStart();
               }

               @Override
               public void onNext(@NonNull List<AlertAssetDTO> listResponse) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onComplete() {

               }
           });
   mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
   ```
4. Wherever you want the connection to be cancelled (e.g. `onDestroy()` method of your `Activity` or `onDestroyView()` of your `Fragment`) call
       mCompositeDisposable.clear();

Multiple disposables may be added to the CompostieDisposable above this way.

Comment: The most important part of the original (v1) answer is that it actually cancels the request: ```Retrofit RxJava connector will redirect this call to okHttp's cancel. See here: ``` .. missing in this answer (the old link is broken now)

Comment: It is still true for Retrofit RxJava2 call adapter will forward disposable signal to okhttp `cancel`. I have updated the link. Just use regular rxjava cancel mechanism, no custom code is needed.