# Retrofit 2 + RxJava cancel/unsubscribe

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am performing a network request where I send files and a message.
I would like to have an option to cancel current request. I have found two similar questions and both suggests that `observable.subscribe(Observer)` returns Subscription object which has method `unsubscribe()`.

[Here is the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727268/how-cancel-task-with-retrofit-and-rxjava)

[And the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199769/how-to-cancel-request-with-retofit2-and-rxandroid)

In my case, I use `observable.subscribe(Observer)` which is void. Here is my code:

```
Observable<MessengerRaw> observable = mModel.sendMessage(message, companion, description, multiParts);
        observable.subscribe(new Observer<MessengerRaw>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(MessengerRaw value) {
                if (getView() != null) {
                    ((MessengerActivity) getView()).resetMessegeView();
                    ((MessengerActivity) getView()).updateMessageList();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                getData().remove(0);
                if (getView() != null) {
                    ((MessengerActivity) getView()).updateMessageList();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                hideProgress();
            }
        });
```

So how do I unsubscribe/cancel my request?
Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In RxJava2, you can get Disposable object in onSubscribe callback method of oserver, which you can use to dispose subscription.

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted because it directly points to the solution. The previously accepted answer was not edited properly. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

In RXJava You must use subscriptions for unsubscribe

```
private Subscription mSubscription;

/.../

Observable<MessengerRaw> observable = mModel.sendMessage(message, companion, description, multiParts);
Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(new Observer<MessengerRaw>() {/.../});
```

When you want to unsubscribe you can call

```
if(!subscription.isUnsubscribed()){
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

In RXJava 2 `observable.subscribe(new Observer<MessengerRaw>() {/.../});` returns Disposable object, you can call dispose();

Comment: observable.subscribe(new Observer<MessengerRaw>() {/.../}); does not have overloaded version that returns Subscription. There are versions that return Disposable, Observable<MessengerRaw>, and void.

Comment: You can call dispose();

Comment: You are right: @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            } has the disposable on which I can call dispose() and request cancels. Thanks. You can include into your answer so others can see it right away.

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: In RxJava 2, there is no `Subscription.unsubscribe()` method, that belongs to RxJava 1.